# Zipped up my dist folder to distribute my Java program but looks very different on another computer

Tags: java, android, executable-jar

I made a simple java program using netbeans GUI and I wanted to be able to run it on a different computer just to see how to looks. I know that Java is known to be able to be run on any device so I don't understand why this is formatted all weird.

The problem is that I made the program on my laptop and it runs perfectly on my laptop. Perfect size. However, when I ran the jar file on my pc, it is very zoomed in to the point where I can't even see the bottom half of my program. How do I fix this?

Also, is there any way for me to run this application on an android phone and maybe even make it an app on the phone?

Comment: Make your question more specific, too few information what are you talking about.

Comment: The difference might be in the machines themselves, especially the resolution of the display. You need to show screenshots and some code in order for us to help you. As for making an Android app, I suggest that you start at https://developer.android.com. Your business logic is probably reusable, but you will have to completely rewrite the UI because native Android does not support Swing.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your PC has a lower resolution compared to your laptop. Let's say your PC has a `1024 x 768` resolution and your laptop has a `1920 x 1080`. It seems that your java program's GUI window has a height bigger than 768 pixels (for example 900 pixels) which justifies the clipping of your program's bottom half. It appears fine on the laptop as the screen height is 1080 pixels and can accommodate a taller window.

Reducing the window height and redesigning your program's GUI interface fixes the problem.

Concerning the next phase of the question: Simply no. You can't port the graphical interface (GUI) to Android, you will need to rewrite it in XML. I suggest you look into [Building Your First App](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html) on the Android Developers website for some help in creating your own Android app.